# Spring boot web starter environment detection - embedded or container

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Gradle, Spring Boot (web starter) application, that is built to be run either as a standalone application with the embedded container, or deployed to a container as a war.

So I from Eclipse I can run/debug the `@SpringBootApplication` class, and also deploy the war in Tomcat. All works fine.

Now, for some requirements, I need to know the running environment; standalone or container. Basically, we generate a MANIFEST file to the war, with a Gradle build, and refer to that file for some version/meta information. However, this would be generated only when built from Gradle. Is there any way in code I can differentiate this?

Comment: What is the requirement? Why do you need to know the environment?

Comment: @M.Deinum, I want to know whether a MANIFEST.MF is present. Basically, I need a way to access the application build version.

Comment: Then why so complex... Just load the file and put some logic in there to handle the non-existence of that file. No need to detect the way the application was run...

Comment: @M.Deinum, well I was expecting Spring-Boot provides some out of the box support, since it can handle an embedded or deployed mode.

Comment: Why do you want to make things more complex then check for a file? Spring Boot doesn't know about the environment it just boots an application.